# Empty row packet in body error, large result set of images

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
$mysqli = new mysqli("server", "user","pass","database") or die(mysqli_error());

$result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM testimage WHERE OCTET_LENGTH( IMAGE ) >200000 ") or die(mysqli_error());


if($result){
 // Cycle through results
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {



    file_put_contents($row['ID'].'.png', $row['IMAGE']);

}


// Free result set
$result->close();


}
?>
```

I'm storing images directly as longblob objects in my test database, I'm attempting to grab all images that are larger than 200k.  When I query in this way I receive two errors.  These are posted below.

If I query without checking the length I get the same errors.

This php is running on my laptop on mac os x if that matters.  This same code worked fine when the database contained a smaller number of images.  The other explanations for this error mention large results sets, but they also mention altering the table, which I do not believe I am doing.

The database contains approximately 440 megs in 1000 images. stored as LONGBLOB objects

Warning: Empty row packet body in Get_All_Images_DB_BLUEHOST2.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli::query(): (00000/0):  in Get_All_Images_DB_BLUEHOST2.php on line 5

Another piece of information, the error always occurs approximately 109 - 120 seconds.

Comment: line 5 is    $result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM testimage WHERE OCTET_LENGTH( IMAGE ) >200000 ") or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange MySQL error "Empty row packet body" when using mysql\_fetch\_object (PHP 5.3.3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780521/strange-mysql-error-empty-row-packet-body-when-using-mysql-fetch-object-php-5)

Comment: I just wanted to update this with the solution that I found, to avoid this error, I used LIMIT to iterate through the database and return smaller sets at a time.

Comment: You should post an answer yourself then.

Comment: okay, thanks for the heads up! will do.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass","database") or die(mysqli_error());
$result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM testimages ") or die(mysqli_error());
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();

$maxid =  $data[0];
$off = 0;
$dur = 50;

for ($i = 1; $i <= ($maxid/50)+1; $i++){

$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass","db") or die(mysqli_error());

$result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM testimage LIMIT $off,$dur ") or die(mysqli_error());



if($result){
 // Cycle through results
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    //echo($row['TAG']);
    //echo(":");

    //$row['IMAGE']
    echo ", ";
    echo ($row['ID']);

    file_put_contents($row['ID'].'.png', $row['IMAGE']);

}


// Free result set
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();


}
$off += 50;
}

?>
```

This is my naive solution to avoid the above error by limiting the result set, by getting the maximum number of results and incrementing up that number using LIMIT.